# Pass body value to another processing step

Tags: java, apache-camel

My problem is, I have to pass exchange body value (which is set in previous route) into `.to("rest:get ...")` step. I'm trying something like in the code below, but class variable `id` is equal to `null` in the important step, even though I'm setting its value in a custom processor one step before. I've also tried using `simple()` function, which can evaluate into exchange body, but the problem is I don't have access to exchange in `.to("rest:get ...")` method, I can only access it inside processor.

How can I pass exchange body value into `.to("rest:get ...")` step?

```java
public class SomeRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @ConfigProperty(name = "rest.external.host")
    String host;

    @ConfigProperty(name = "rest.external.endpoint")
    String endpoint;

    String id;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        restConfiguration().host(host);

        from("direct:routeEntry")
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, log, body().toString())
                .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
                .removeHeader(Exchange.HTTP_PATH)
                .removeHeaders("Camel*")
                .process(exchange -> {
                    id = exchange.getIn().getBody().toString();
                })
                .to("rest:get:" + endpoint + "/" + id)
                .convertBodyTo(String.class);
       }
    }
```

Comment: The id variable only exists in the process you never set it to the exchange again. Either set it as a property or header and then use it.

Answer (score 1):

Use **dynamic** to , aka "toD":

```
.toD("rest:get:" + endpoint + "/${body}")
```

Answer (score 0):

To explain why the id is null more simply: the value of that class variable is only read at the time of route instantiation.

The reason for it only being read once is that the endpoint URI is constructed once during route building and every execution uses it after the route has been built and started.

To get the result you want you need to use a dynamic to, like @TachaDeChoco said.

In dynamic to you can use simple-syntax to construct the final URI during route execution.